# Google maps: is possible to insert moving markers which are able moving only on the streets?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps, maps

I would like to ask that is possible to do this thing in the Google maps.

I have **marker A** which is displayed on map on some GPS coords.

I would like to add **marker B** which is randomly displayed in some radius from marker A (for example on the passed GPS coords).

**Marker B** should to **start getting closer** to Marker A with constant speed.

Marker B should to move closer to Marker A only on the streets,paths, grass, meadow (it means not throught the walls, water, etc).

Is it possible in Google Maps API?

And if Yes, could someone provide some example or link to tutorial?

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You want to animate your marker along route. It is possible with google maps api.
Look at the below url.
https://duncan99.wordpress.com/2015/01/22/animated-paths-with-google-maps/

Hope it helps you.